# Background handling push notification on FCM Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a problem, I really understand the functionality of push notifications and their use; But, I have this situation, when the push notification arrives and I click on it perfect, I update the activity, the problem I have is that the push notification arrives and the user does not push the push notification but opens the application directly; When this happens the activity is not updated. Is there any method embedded or experimental that just get the push the activity in the background update its functionality as when I click on the push?

In short, what I look for is that when the push arrives, update the components of the activity (background), when open the application should be updated without needing to press the push notification; That is to say that the push notification would only be informative but the user would not push the push notification but it will open the application and in it it will be reworked the actions as it would have been if it had pressed the push.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

When the push arrives trigger a background service from your onMessageReceived method of FirebaseMessagingService class. Although FirebaseMessagingService is itself a Service class , in this case you can just use your FirebaseMessagingService class. In this scenario you notify the user via push once your background task is complete.

Here is a basic skeleton about how you should solve it using your FirebaseMessagingService class.

```
  public class PushFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

   // Define the listener interface
   interface BackgroundTaskCompletionListener<T> {
       void requestComplete(T object);
   }

   @Override
   public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       doBackgrundTask(new BackgroundTaskCompletionListener<Boolean>(){
           @Override
           public void requestComplete(Boolean object) {

           }
       });
       notifyUser(remoteMessage);
   }

   public void doBackgrundTask(BackgroundTaskCompletionListener mBackgroundTaskCompletionListener){
       boolean taskcomplete = false;

       //do your task

       if(mBackgroundTaskCompletionListener!=null){
           mBackgroundTaskCompletionListener.requestComplete(taskcomplete);
       }
   }

   public void notifyUser(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
       //your notification
   }

 }
```

Although one other way you can quickly solve your problem is by setting a preference value from your FirebaseMessagingService class. In this case when activity opens up, you can check whether the preference value is set or not based on that you can do your update regardless of whether the push was clicked or not.

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Comment: If you uninstall the application everything will be gone for that application including preference and every other app related data. I don't understand your question what uninstalling has to do with your push notification or anything else.

Comment: Do you have an example?